# Delete and Select Concurrency in Different Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, concurrency

This may be a dumb question, but I'm not really sure if the way I'm approaching the creation of these stored procedures could be causing any issues.

My select stored procedure looks like so:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSRPsToProcess]
    @CurrentTime DateTime
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN Tran1
        Select TOP 20 *
        From SRPQueue WITH (updlock, ROWLOCK, readpast)
        WHERE SRPQueue.TimeToDequeue <= @CurrentTime AND SRPQueue.Status = 'Pending'
        ORDER BY SRPQueue_Index 
    COMMIT
END
```

My delete procedure looks like so (and will eventually also contain an insert to a log table):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DequeueRelevantSRPs]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @SRPQueue_Index int,
    -- @TimeDeleted datetime
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN Tran1
        Delete
        FROM SRPQueue
        WHERE SRPQueue.SRPQueue_Index = @SRPQueue_Index
    COMMIT
END
```

Would the best practice to avoid the issue of my DequeueRelevantSRPs stored procedure attempting to delete an already selected, locked row (and failing), be to use the SRPQueue.Status variable?

This would be nice, as I could have a few different statuses (pending, processing, ready, failed) and I'd just need an additional AND SRPQueue.Status = 'Ready' check. Is there another method that can make sure the delete succeeds despite the potential lock on it?

Edit: The application that calls these stored procedures will be running in multiple instances on multiple servers.  Kind of an important detail >.>.

Comment: Er, I'm not sure that first stored procedure is going to _maintain_ the locks it grabs during the `SELECT` statement.  At least, in DB2, locks are usually released on a `COMMIT`...  Potentially, you'd want to pull the commit level out to a higher level anyways, but if those are running in the same thread, I think it would allow the `DELETE` anyways.  You either need to maintain your locks (and have other statements skip them), or flag a row as being processed, unlock it, and tell other statements to ignore flagged row.

Comment: Derp, I forgot to clarify that the application calling these stored procedures will have multiple instances on multiple servers, which changes the dynamic quite a bit.

Comment: ...Especially then, you may wish to 'register' running (processing) jobs to the system, flag checkouts by job, then setup some sort of monitor job to alert operators/de-register jobs if one of them hasn't done anything in a while.  Otherwise, you probably need an overarching transaction for the entire thing (not per-statement).  Although I'm not sure whether that `TOP 20` is only going to _lock_ the 'top 20' rows, or the entire set (probably depends on if you have an index on that column), or what effect that has on attempting to `INSERT` 'higher' rows.

Comment: Could that process not be alleviated merely by updating the QueueStatus inside the same transaction in which the rows are selected and then checking for said updated status in the delete?  On that note, is there any way to do a select and update at the same time (perhaps by using output)?  As for the second half, I believe the rowlock, updatelock, and readpast should ensure that only the top 20 rows are locked and not the entire set.  Otherwise, I have a fairly flawed understanding of how they work =/.

Comment: DB2 at least supports 'data change table references', which means you can do something like `SELECT FROM NEW TABLE (INSERT...)`, and get the new rows.  This kind of thing is implementation specific, but I think I saw that some versions of SQL Server had similar syntax.  Oh, and I'm assuming that you only want to delete those rows that a particular job was running over.

Answer (score 0):

The Insert, Update and Delete instructions LOCKs the Tables within the Transactions, And the Select Wait for the Tables unlocked...

I will make the 1st SP without the TRAN

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSRPsToProcess]
    @CurrentTime DateTime
AS
BEGIN

        Select TOP 20 *
        From SRPQueue WITH (updlock, ROWLOCK, readpast)
        WHERE SRPQueue.TimeToDequeue <= @CurrentTime AND SRPQueue.Status = 'Pending'
        ORDER BY SRPQueue_Index 

END
```